# How can I get IntelliJ IDEA to recognize the GPars DSL?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, dsl, gpars

According to the [GPars User Guide](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html#2.4%20Getting%20Set-up%20in%20an%20IDE), IntelliJ IDEA is supposed to be able to recognize the GPars DSL right out of the box as soon as the GPars jar is added to the project. Since Groovy 1.8, GPars is now included in the Groovy distribution, but adding that facet to the IDEA project doesn't seem to help.

Does anyone know how I can activate the DSL support? It would be *really* nice to have the DSL keywords recognized instead of having little underlines everywhere.

<sub>Note: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate v11.1</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems GPars jar from Groovy distribution doesn't contain gdsl script which teaches IDEA to work with GPars dsl.
The simplest thing you could do is to add this gdsl file in your project
http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=gpars.git;a=blob;f=src/main/groovy/groovyx/gpars/Definitions.gdsl;h=49f6993221645e3d887e6bf99c3c0fc46afef69e;hb=b0155a809a5c9adf9de816f18121d5a60d4b455d

Comment: This ticket has been fixed in GPars v1.0 (just released). I haven't checked yet, but this issue should be solved!